# sqoop not import datatype varchar2

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, varchar2

sqoop not import datatype varchar2 to hadoop 
I have a table in oracle Database and I want import the data to hdfs.
I am trying to do it with sqoop, but varchar2 columns are not imported.
I mean that these data isn't arriving to hdfs file.
my sqoop command

```
sqoop import -D mapred.job.name='default oraoop'  --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:MyIp:MyServiceName" --username "XXXX" --password "XX" --target-dir "My_dir" --query 'select * from MyTable where $CONDITIONS' --split-by "coulmn"  --boundary-query "SELECT min(splitColumn),max(SplitCoulmn)  FROM DUAL" --num-mappers 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to downgrade the ojdbc instead of using higher ojdbc "ojdbc6 or ojdbc7" use "ojdbc14" this solved the problem for me but in order not to face an exception with some encoding classes not being found remove or rename the "ori18n.jar" while importing data from the orale9i.

you can find the paths to these jar files in "**$HADOOP_CLASSPATH**" and "**$SQOOP_HOME**"

Answer (score 0):

May be sqoop couldn't identify the matching java type of `VARCHAR2`, so try with -`-map-column-java`.

let's say column A is the `VARCHAR2` type then your sqoop command would be,

sqoop import -D mapred.job.name='default oraoop'  --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:MyIp:MyServiceName" --username "XXXX" --password "XX" --target-dir "My_dir" --query 'select * from MyTable where $CONDITIONS' **--map-column-java a=String** --split-by "coulmn"  --boundary-query "SELECT min(splitColumn),max(SplitCoulmn)  FROM DUAL" --num-mappers 30

let me know if this works.

Comment: I tried it and i got this error 16/11/09 04:20:12 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: No ResultSet method for Java type string

Comment: 'S' should be capital in `String`.. I have edited the command can you try now?

Comment: I tried it but still varchar2 columns are not imported

Comment: So you are getting Null values?

Comment: can you also try dumping into hive and specify `--map-column-hive` and let me know.

Comment: I tried      --map-column-hive   but still varchar2 columns are not imported

Comment: Mohamed, instead of giving `--query`  try with `--columns c1,c2,...`.

Comment: I got this Error when I used --columns Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter

Comment: sqoop import -D mapred.job.name='default oraoop'  --driver oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@MyIp:MyServiceName" --username "XXX" --password "XXX" --target-dir "MyDir" --map-column-hive A=String --table 'MyTable' --split-by "x"  --boundary-query "SELECT Min(x),Max(x) FROM DUAL" --num-mappers 30  --hive-import --hive-table  xxx  --columns AA,BB

Comment: this is my command I just removed some data like IP, username ,Password , table names etc..

Comment: so you masked column names also? at least if you could provide me the columns from source table and its data type will be help full to analyze